# Check if process runs if not execute script.sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to find a way to monitor a process. If the process is not running it should be checked again to make sure it has really crashed. If it has really crashed run a script (start.sh)

I have tried monit with no succes, I have also tried adding this script in crontab:  I made it executable with chmod +x monitor.sh

the actual program is called program1

```
case "$(pidof program | wc -w)" in

0)  echo "Restarting program1:     $(date)" >> /var/log/program1_log.txt
/home/user/files/start.sh &
;;
1)  # all ok
;;
*)  echo "Removed double program1: $(date)" >> /var/log/program1_log.txt
kill $(pidof program1 | awk '{print $1}')
;; 
esac
```

The problem is this script does not work, I added it to crontab and set it to run every 2 minutes. If I close the program it won't restart.

Is there any other way to check a process, and run start.sh when it has crashed?

Comment: Yes, the way to do this is with a monitoring tool like `monit` or the dozen other such tools that exist. If you can't use that (and don't want to ask for help about **that** then how is this script not working? What *is* the script doing?

Comment: Run `supervisor` or the like, no reason to reinvent the wheel / NIH-syndrome.

Comment: One possible direct answer is to place the nohup command in front of the command to run the script: nohup /home/user/files/start.sh &   -- the other posters are correct, there exist well-tested ways to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Not to be rude, but have you considered a more obvious solution?

When a shell (e.g. bash or tcsh) starts a subprocess, by default it waits for that subprocess to complete.

So why not have a shell that runs your process in a while(1) loop?  Whenever the process terminates, for any reason, legitimate or not, it will automatically restart your process.

I ran into this same problem with mythtv.  The backend keeps crashing on me.  It's a Heisenbug.  Happens like once a month (on average).  Very hard to track down.  So I just wrote a little script that I run in an xterm.

The, ahh, ***oninter*** business means that control-c will terminate the subprocess and not my (parent-process) script.  Similarly, the sleep is in there so I can control-c several times to kill the subprocess and then kill the parent-process script while it's sleeping...

Coredumpsize is limited just because I don't want to fill up my disk with corefiles that I cannot use.

```
#!/bin/tcsh -f

limit coredumpsize 0

while( 1 )

   echo "`date`:  Running mythtv-backend"

      # Now we cannot control-c this (tcsh) process...
   onintr -

      # This will let /bin/ls directory-sort my logfiles based on day & time.
      # It also keeps the logfile names pretty unique.
   mythbackend |& tee /....../mythbackend.log.`date "+%Y.%m.%d.%H.%M.%S"`

      # Now we can control-c this (tcsh) process.
   onintr

   echo "`date`:  mythtv-backend exited.  Sleeping for 30 seconds, then restarting..."
   sleep 30

end
```

p.s. That sleep will also save you in the event your subprocess dies immediately.  Otherwise the constant respawning without delay will drive your IO and CPU through the roof, making it difficult to correct the problem.